# Bayesian MCMC Fitting

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, markov-process, fitting, prior

I am doing a Bayesian MCMC fit using emcee in python. I first maximize the log of the likelihood and use the results as initial parameter starting points in my MCMC. I am using a uniform prior and Gaussian likelihood.

I sometimes find that maximizing the likelihood gives non-physical values outside the bounds set by my prior, and it causes the MCMC to not sample the parameter space. Is there a way around this besides making the prior boundaries large enough to include these non-physical values?

I would still like the MCMC to sample the parameter space, and once the chain stabilizes, I always find it stays away from these unphysical regions.

Comment: Maximise the likelihood under the constraints.